# advance elasticsearch golang

Tags: go, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have performed general search in my chat application where a user can search message or file, it work fine using `go-elasticsearch` package.For it I created mapping according to requirements of general search like this for `messages`. i.e.
[image]
and for files I have created following mapping
[image]
and for search query of ELS I put condition on two fields like for `message` search `message.term` AND `message.channelid` , for `file` search query used two fields `file.name` AND `file.channelid`. But now I want to perform advance elastic search for `message` and `file` search. How can I create search query or search logic for advance message search and advance file search using elastic search. I have attached screenshot for both advance search required field.
i.e.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to perform advance elastic search for `message` and `file` search. How can I create search query or search logic for advance message search and advance file search using elastic search. I have attached screenshot for both advance search required field.
i.e.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [Query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) or [Simple string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html).  You can use filters, quotes, and excluding terms.

Another way would be converting the filter params to Elasticsearch query on application.

This is an example code to build query using simple string query and struct params to build advanced search query in Go!

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8/typedapi/core/search"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8/typedapi/types"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8/typedapi/types/enums/simplequerystringflag"
)

type MessageSearchParams struct {
    Query   string
    Filters *MessageSearchFilters
    Size    int
}

type MessageSearchFilters struct {
    UserIDs      []string
    ChannelIDs   []string
    MinCreatedAt time.Time
    MaxCreatedAt time.Time
}

func buildMessageSearchQuery(params *MessageSearchParams) (json.RawMessage, error) {
    // build elasticsearch query here
    var filters []types.QueryContainer
    if len(params.Filters.ChannelIDs) > 0 {
        filters = append(filters, types.QueryContainer{
            Terms: &types.TermsQuery{
                TermsQuery: map[types.Field]types.TermsQueryField{
                    "channel_id": params.Filters.ChannelIDs,
                },
            },
        })
    }
    if !params.Filters.MinCreatedAt.IsZero()  || !params.Filters.MaxCreatedAt.IsZero() {
        var gt, lt *types.DateMath
        if !params.Filters.MinCreatedAt.IsZero() {
            minCreatedAtStr := types.DateMath(strconv.FormatInt(params.Filters.MinCreatedAt.UnixMilli(), 10))
            gt = &minCreatedAtStr
        }
        if !params.Filters.MaxCreatedAt.IsZero() {
            maxCreatedAtStr := types.DateMath(strconv.FormatInt(params.Filters.MaxCreatedAt.UnixMilli(), 10))
            lt = &maxCreatedAtStr
        }
        filters = append(filters, types.QueryContainer{
            Range: map[types.Field]types.RangeQuery{
                "created_at": types.DateRangeQuery{
                    Gt: gt,
                    Lt: lt,
                },
            },
        })
    }

    queryStringFlag := types.NewSimpleQueryStringFlagsBuilder().
        SimpleQueryStringFlag(simplequerystringflag.PHRASE).
        SimpleQueryStringFlag(simplequerystringflag.NOT).
        Build()
    req := &search.Request{
        Query: &types.QueryContainer{
            Bool: &types.BoolQuery{
                Must: []types.QueryContainer{
                    {
                        SimpleQueryString: &types.SimpleQueryStringQuery{
                            Query: params.Query,
                            Flags: &queryStringFlag,
                        },
                    },
                },
                Filter: filters,
            },
        },
    }

    return json.Marshal(req)
}
```

The above example is with typed api but also there are multiple ways to build query dynamically in Go.

- [Typed API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/go-api/current/examples.html#search)
- Go template
- map[string]interface{}
- [CUE](https://cuelang.org/)

Comment: thank you for your response. Above code through this error, `QueryContainer not declared by package types in this code` , also can you give me  idea how can we manage excluded feature using query container. I need more clarity about above code.